# How to use RestTemplate with non String Query Params in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, resttemplate, query-string

I'm using RestTemplate in a Spring Boot project, and I have 4 query params, 2 of them are String, one is BigDecimal and one is boolean: String name, String channel, BigDecimal code, boolean isCreated. I want to ask you how to send this non String query params because I see that getQueryParams() require a Map<String, String>.

I'm using this kind of implementation:

```
    UriComponents uriComponents = UriComponentsBuilder
            .fromHttpUrl(basePath)
            .path(apiPath)
            .getQueryParams(map)
            .encode();
```

Any feedback will be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For `BigDecimal` and `Boollean`, you can try using the `toString()` and `valueOf()` methods.

```
public String createUriString(){
    String basePath="http://example.com";
    String apiPath="api";
    String name="example_name";
    String channel="example_channel";
    BigDecimal code = BigDecimal.valueOf(100500);
    boolean isCreated= true;
    MultiValueMap<String,String> params = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    params.set("name",name);
    params.set("channel",channel);
    params.set("code",code.toString());
    params.set("isCreated",String.valueOf(isCreated));
    UriComponents uriComponents = UriComponentsBuilder
        .fromHttpUrl(basePath)
        .path(apiPath)
        .queryParams(params)
            .build();
    return uriComponents.toUriString();
}
```

> http://example.com/apiname=example_name&channel=example_channel&code=100500&isCreated=true

You can also use the QueryParam method. It's easier.

```
public String createUriString(){
    String basePath="http://example.com";
    String apiPath="api";
    String name="example_name";
    String channel="example_channel";
    BigDecimal code = BigDecimal.valueOf(100500);
    boolean isCreated= true;
    UriComponents uriComponents = UriComponentsBuilder
            .fromHttpUrl(basePath)
            .path(apiPath)
            .queryParam("name",name)
            .queryParam("channel", channel)
            .queryParam("code", code)
            .queryParam("isCreated", isCreated)
            .build();
    return uriComponents.toUriString();
}
```

The result of this code is similar to the previous example.

P.S. I couldn't find getQueryParams(map) method.We may have different versions of Spring Boot.